# Filter a dataframe with NOT and AND condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but for some reason it is not working for my case.

So I want to filter the dataframe using the NOT and AND condition.
For example, my dataframe df looks like:

```
col1    col2
a       1
a       2
b       3
b       4
b       5
c       6
```

Now, I want to use a condition to remove where `col1 has "a" AND col2 has 2`
My resulting dataframe should look like:

```
col1    col2
a       1
b       3
b       4
b       5
c       6
```

I tried this: Even though I used `&` but it removes all the rows which have "a" in col1 .

```
df = df[(df['col1'] != "a") & (df['col2'] != "2")]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove cells where `col1 is "a" AND col2 is 2` means to keep cells where `col1 isn't "a" OR col2 isn't 2` (negation of `A AND B` is `NOT(A) OR NOT(B)`):

```
df = df[(df['col1'] != "a") | (df['col2'] != 2)]   #   or "2", depending on whether the `2` is an int or a str
```